# Why doesn't the Teflon coating in cookware melt?

Tags: temperature, everyday-life, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

Teflon's melting point is 327 degrees Celsius, whereas a regular gas stove easily reaches temperatures above this. So why doesn't the Teflon coating in cookware melt while cooking?